# make a continuous beep sound until interrupted in c#

Tags: c#, audio, beep

I want to make a continuous beep sound in my application until interrupted.
**Approach**

1. Display a message box with **retry cancel** button
2. Make beep sound continuously until I press Cancel
3. If a press Retry the beep sound should not stop

I tried this using Console.beep() but it only makes sound once.

Any ideas??

Comment: Your users are going to love that feature.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195828/c-produce-a-continuous-tone-until-interrupted

Comment: I had Tried this but It only plays beep sound when Retry is clicked<br\>
`public void retry()
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Item cannot be found", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                Console.Beep(5000, 250);
                retry();
            }            
        }`

Comment: Post your code in your question, not in comment section!

Answer (score 3):

As you  know of course , this method has more constructors... you can specify it's `frequency` and `duration` :

```
Console.Beep(100,10000);
```

Another suggestion for your case is just to loop it according to a boolean variable:

```
   bool stop = false;

        while (!stop)
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
```

Comment: @Jamiec 
I had tried this but the second parameter is time bound, which my senior is not happy with. He wants to play it continuously.

Comment: @GajendraRajput you mean play it forever? infinitly?

Comment: Kind of but should stop when cancel is clicked.

Comment: @GajendraRajput i understand.edited see my updated answer please.

Comment: @GajendraRajput - slightly confused why (and how!!) you're telling me this

Comment: @Jamiec why are you confused man? what was not clear in my answer ? :)

Comment: Im confused because I literally have nothing to do with this question or answer... oh. wait. I just edited this answer - it had a spelling mistake. It's @Slashy you meant to reference.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Beep();` has two arguments, length and tone.

Use like this: `Console.Beep(tone_in_hz, length_in_milliseconds);`

You could also create a new thread and a public boolean and then run a while loop, like so:

```
private void Beeper()
{
    while(makeBeepSound)
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public void Beep()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Message", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) == DialogResult.Retry)
        {
                Console.Beep(5000, 5000);
                Beep();
        }
    }
```

In Form1 load event

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Beep();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place Beep() in a loop and start it in a new tread. For instance:

```
    class Beeper
    {
        private int _gapMiliseconds;
        private bool _stop = false;

        public Beeper(int gapMiliseconds)
        {
            _gapMiliseconds = gapMiliseconds;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            while (!_stop)
            {
                Console.Beep();
                Thread.Sleep(_gapMiliseconds);
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _stop = true;
        }
    }
```

and a code to start and stop it as a thread.

```
        Beeper beeper = new Beeper(100);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(beeper.Start));
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        beeper.Stop();
```

Comment: The solution you provided didn't help