# Console.Beep how to remove delay in loop?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to make a program, where you enter a number and it kind of generates a track of the number. It splits it into digits and plays a different Beep depending on the digit. But there is a delay between the Beeps. Here is the code of the project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbersWithBeeps = new int [] { 262, 294, 330, 349, 392, 440, 494, 523, 600, 687, 878};
            int input;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you would like to play.");
            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            input*=10;
            List<int> actualNumbers = new List<int>();
            do{
                if(input%10 == 0) 
                {
                    actualNumbers.Add(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    actualNumbers.Add(input%10);
                }
                input=input/10;
            } while(input > 0);

            for(int i = actualNumbers.Count - 1; i > 0; i--){
                Console.Beep(numbersWithBeeps[actualNumbers[i]], 500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How long is the delay in milliseconds?

Comment: Have you tried changing the duration of the beep with the second argument to `Console.Beep`?  When I tried it there seems to be a noise after each beep and not a real delay, but it could be different when run on different hardware.

Comment: Note that according to [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1196069/5095502): "Calling Console.Beep() from a separate thread interrupts whatever is currently in progress.", so assuming the delay is simply the literal delay on the `if` statement iterating and delays in new `Beep` call making it to the hardware, then a potential answer is to create the `878` beep in one thread, then *while it's still playing* create the `687` beep in a different thread and it may play it without a delay between 878->687.

Comment: @DanWilson It seems to be about half a second
Juharr Yeah, I tried it, but I think that there is a different delay with different times. I know that there isn't any logic, but this is the only way I can explain it to myself right now.
Quantic I will try this and tell you what happened

Answer (score 0):

The delay is due to the `for` loop iteration.  It's not going to **Beep** while it's not on an iteration that doesn't contain one of your `numbersWithBepps[]`.  It also seems that your whole `do{}while` loop is unnecessary.  A lot of what you're doing doesn't make sense to me.  You want the user to pick the tone played?  Then why not

```
int iSoundId;
getsound: Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of sound you want to hear:\t");
iSoundId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine();
if (iSoundId < 32,767)
    Console.Beep(iSoundId, 500);
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number too high...  Try again:\n);
    goto getSound;
}
```

Also, like **juharr** stated, your duration might be what's effecting it.  Try just lowering your duration to **250** instead of 500 milliseconds.

Comment: I don't want the user to pick it, the whole point of the program is that the user enters a number and a track generates of it, so the user doesn't know what he is going to hear. Later on I plan on adding something like different "seeds". Depending on the "seed" the track will sound totally different each time.

Comment: And I'm sure the users don't know what pitch of beep it will be, as the integer value is based on the hertz level applied to the speaker.  Either way, like I said, you can try lowering your **duration** time to 250 or lower.  It should remedy the problem.  Try that and let me know if it works...  Otherwise, I'll try to figure something more detailed out for you.

Comment: That delay is REALLY there, absolutely unrelated to the loop around it. Console.Beep has a delay after the tone and it's very annoying.